# Issue with Accessing .java files with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Sorry for the kind of vague question, but I am experiencing an issue with the Eclipse IDE. I wanted to have a new black UI and I did just that. However, I had to download a newer version of Eclipse for it to work. While I can open up my Eclipse to access my usual workspace. I can't go into those files individually and open them with Eclipse.

When I right click on a .java file, I select Open With > Choose default program > I browse and select Eclipse, but nothing else happens. For extra clarity, I've downloaded the latest standard version for the Windows 7 64 bit operating system. What can I do to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should follow these steps
File > Import > General > Existing Project into WorkSpace 
then add your project via browse button

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse organize code into projects under workspaces. To import the java files you need to import the project containing those java  files.

Comment: I do have that, but with the older version of Eclipse I had, I could select Eclipse as my default program when dealing with .java class. However, I can't do that anymore. This also means that when I click on a java file with the windows explorer, It doesn't automatically open up eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

you have to import entire project  into eclips not only .java file.